# Why fgets cannot get all bytes from a popen stream

Tags: c, popen, fgets

I compiled the following code and run:

`$ ./run_curl 'http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/grep-2.4.tar.gz'`.

But I cannot get full bytes of the file I want to download. Why?

I use `curl --silent 'http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/grep-2.4.tar.gz' > a.tgz` would get the full bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 512

void download_pkg(const char* url)
{
    char content[SIZE] = {0};
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char cmd[255] = {0};
    FILE *fp_download = fopen("a.tgz", "w");
    sprintf(cmd, "curl --silent '%s'", url);
    fp = popen(cmd, "r");
    while(fgets(content, SIZE - 1, fp) != NULL) {
        fputs(content, fp_download);
    }
    fclose(fp_download);
    pclose(fp);
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    download_pkg(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:

According Jonathan Leffler's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29054978/665869), problem solved by the following code:

```
int size_read = 0;
while((size_read = fread(content, sizeof(char), SIZE - 1, fp)) > 0) {
    fwrite(content, sizeof(char), size_read, fp_download);
}
```

Comment: There is no error checking here. Are you sure you read a part of the file?

Comment: @G I removed some code, it was too many code than text that SO did not allow me to submit the question. I don't think it's because only download part of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gzipped tar file will contain numerous null bytes.  These null bytes will screw up the processing of data read via `fgets()`.  You will miss the null bytes and any other bytes after them.  `fgets()` does not tell you how many bytes it read, so you cannot safely read past the null bytes.

You need to use `fread()` and `fwrite()`, most probably.  At least, those will not be confused by embedded nulls in the data.